# Is this a contradiction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I have proven that a group has **one and only one element** $a$ such that $a=a^2$, that is $a$ is the square of itself.

However, then I encounter this question about finding $2\times 2$ matrices such that $A=A^2$. It turned out that there are more than one of them.

Could anyone explain why that is the case? I understand that these "special" matrices are in a group of matrices.

The three matrices I have found so far are:
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
,\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
and the zero matrix.

Thank you very much.

Nick

Comment: Your argument, presumably, depended on the fact that you had a group.  The zero matrix is not in the multiplicative group of two by two matrices.

Comment: Your second example does not satisfy $A = A^2$, There are however lots of non-zero, non-identity examples. e.g., $\left[\matrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}\right]$. Examples other than the identity have to be non-invertible otherwise your argument about elements of a group applies.

Comment: Matrices, with multiplication, make up a *monoid*, but it is not a *group*, because not all matrices are invertible. In this case, there will surely be only one *invertible* matrix $A$ with the property $A^2=A$ (which happens to be the identity matrix), plus there may be many non-invertible matrices with the same property.

Answer (score 2):

Since your group operation is matrix multiplication, there is no zero element in your group.  The identity is the identity matrix.  Second, your second matrix squared is not itself, but the identity.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for the 2nd matrix, call it $A$.

Here $A^2= I$ is the identity matrix and not $A$.

Zero matrix is absorbing in the sense that $O\cdot A = O = A\cdot O$ for each matrix $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$a=a^2\implies a^{-1}a=a^{-1}a^2\implies a=e$(identity element) holds.

The validity of above implication is due to the guaranteed existence of $a^{-1}$ in group as you pre-multiplied by this inverse element. Such existence can not be promised in case of matrices so $A=A^2\not\implies A=I$(identity matrix) unless you are dealing with a multiplicative group of invertible matrices.